# How to convert Dynamic to Forall something

Tags: haskell

I have a cache with Dynamic values. Some of them have the type `Delayed a`.

Normally when I access the cache, I know the type `a`, so it's not a problem, I can use `fromDynamic` to cast to `Maybe a`.

I would like to call a function which doesn't need to know anything about the type `a` on a list of `Dynamic`. (The method is `cancel :: Delay a -> IO ()`).
Is there a way to do so ?

Basically I need a way to do get from `Dynamic` to `Forall a . Delayed a` ?

#### Edit

For information, Delayed holds a pending asynchronous value and a MVar to start or Cancel it. It is equivalent to

```
 data Delayed m a = Delayed { blocker :: MVar Bool, async :: Async m a }
```

Such values are stored in a cache (which use Dynamic and store other things). When displaying the cache status, I need to be able to get the status of `Delayed` value (which involve accessing the blocker but has nothing to do with the actual value.

Comment: What you actually need is a value of type `exists a . Delayed a`. You can express this by a function of type `Dynamic -> (forall a . Typeable a => Delayed a -> r) -> r` (which is an encoding of `Dynamic -> exists a . Typeable a => Delayed a`). Note that passing `cancel` as the 2nd argument of such a function is valid. As of GHC 8.2, you can use [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#v:Con-39-). Before 8.2, you'll have to resort to pattern matching on the `TypeRep` and then using `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: How do I write such a function ? Can you elaborate (both unsafeCoerce and GHC 8.2 solution ) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A value of type `forall a . X a` is a value which can be instantiated to any of `X Int`, `X Bool`, `X String`, etc. Presumably, your cache stores values of many different types, but no single value is valid at every possible type parameter. What you actually need is a value of type `exists a . Delayed a`. However, Haskell doesn't have first-class existential quantifiers, so you must encode that type in some way. One particular encoding is:

```
castToDelayed :: (forall a . Typeable a => Delayed a -> r) -> Dynamic -> r
```

Assume that you have this function; then you can simply write `castToDelayed cancel :: Dynamic -> IO ()`. Note that the function parameter to `castToDelayed` provides a `Typeable` constraint, but you can freely ignore that constraint (which is what `cancel` is doing). Also note this function must be partial due to its type alone (clearly not every `Dynamic` is a `Delayed a` for some `a`), so in real code, you should produce e.g. `Maybe r` instead. Here I will elide this detail and just throw an error.

How you actually write this function will depend on which version of GHC you are using (the most recent, 8.2, or some older version). On 8.2, this is a very nice, simple function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
-- NB: probably requires some other extensions

import Data.Dynamic
import Type.Reflection

castToDelayed :: (forall a . Typeable a => Delayed a -> r) -> Dynamic -> r
castToDelayed k (Dynamic (App (eqTypeRep (typeRep :: TypeRep Delayed) -> Just HRefl) a) x)
  = withTypeable a (k x) 
castToDelayed _ _ = error "Not a Delayed"
```

(Aside: at first I thought the `Con` pattern synonym would be useful here, but on deeper inspection it seems entirely useless. You must use `eqTypeRep` instead.)

Briefly, this function works as follows:

- It pattern matches on the `Dynamic` value to obtain the actual value (of some existentially quantified type `a`) stored within, and the representation of its type (of type `TypeRep a`).
- It pattern matches on the `TypeRep a` to determine if it is an application (using `App`). Clearly, `Delayed a` is the application of a type constructor, so that is the first thing we must check.
- It compares the type constructor (the first argument to `App`) to the `TypeRep` corresponding to `Delayed` (note you must have an `instance Typeable Delayed` for this). If that comparison is successful, it pattern matches on the proof (that is `Just HRefl`) that the first argument to `App` and `Delayed` are in fact the same type.
- At this point, the compiler knows that `a ~ Delayed x` for some `x`. So, you can call the function `forall a . Typeable a => Delayed a -> r` on the value `x :: a`. It must also provide the proof that `x` is `Typeable`, which is given precisely by a value of type `TypeRep x` - `withTypeable` reifies this value-level proof as a type-level constraint (alternatively, you could have the input function take as argument `TypeRep a`, or just omit the constrain altogether, since your specific use case doesn't need it; but this type is the most general possible).

On older versions, the principle is basically the same. However, `TypeRep` did not take a type parameter then; you can pattern match on it to discover if it is the `TypeRep` corresponding to `Delayed`, but you cannot prove to the compiler that the value stored inside the `Dynamic` has type `Delayed x` for some `x`. It will therefore require `unsafeCoerce`, at the step where you are applying the function `k` to the value `x`. Furthermore, there is no `withTypeable` before GHC 8.2, so you will have to write the function with type `(forall a . Delayed a -> r) -> Dynamic -> r` instead (which, fortunately, is enough for your use case); or implement such a function yourself (see the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Typeable.Internal.html#withTypeable) of the function to see how; the implementation on older versions of GHC will be similar, but will have type `TypeRep -> (forall a . Typeable a => Proxy a -> r) -> r` instead).

Here is how you implement this in GHC < 8.2 (tested on 8.0.2). It is a horrible hack, and I make no claim it will correctly in all circumstances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, MagicHash, ScopedTypeVariables, PolyKinds, ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Typeable
import Unsafe.Coerce
import GHC.Prim (Proxy#)
import Data.Proxy

-- This part reifies a `Typeable' dictionary from a `TypeRep'.
-- This works because `Typeable' is a class with a single field, so 
-- operationally `Typeable a => r' is the same as `(Proxy# a -> TypeRep) -> r'
newtype MagicTypeable r (kp :: KProxy k) =
  MagicTypeable (forall (a :: k) . Typeable a => Proxy a -> r)

withTypeRep :: MagicTypeable r (kp :: KProxy k)
            -> forall a . TypeRep -> Proxy a -> r
withTypeRep d t = unsafeCoerce d ((\_ -> t) :: Proxy# a -> TypeRep)

withTypeable :: forall r . TypeRep -> (forall (a :: k) . Typeable a => Proxy a -> r) -> r
withTypeable t k = withTypeRep (MagicTypeable k) t Proxy

-- The type constructor for Delayed
delayed_tycon = fst $ splitTyConApp $ typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy Delayed)

-- This is needed because Dynamic doesn't export its constructor, and
-- we need to pattern match on it.
data DYNAMIC = Dynamic TypeRep Any

unsafeViewDynamic :: Dynamic -> DYNAMIC
unsafeViewDynamic = unsafeCoerce

-- The actual implementation, much the same as the one on GHC 8.2, but more 
-- 'unsafe' things
castToDelayed :: (forall a . Typeable a => Delayed a -> r) -> Dynamic -> r
castToDelayed k (unsafeViewDynamic -> Dynamic t x) =
  case splitTyConApp t of
    (((== delayed_tycon) -> True), [a]) ->
      withTypeable a $ \(_ :: Proxy (a :: *)) -> k (unsafeCoerce x :: Delayed a)
    _ -> error "Not a Delayed"
```

I don't know what `Delayed` actually is, but lets assume it's defined as follows for testing purposes:

```
data Delayed a = Some a | None deriving (Typeable, Show)
```

Then consider this simple test case:

```
test0 :: Typeable a => Delayed a -> String
test0 (Some x) = maybe "not a String" id $ cast x
test0 None     = "None"

test0' =
  let c = castToDelayed test0 in
   [ c (toDyn (None :: Delayed Int))
   , c (toDyn (Some 'a'))
   , c (toDyn (Some "a")) ]
```

Comment: I managed to get something working using `unsafeCoerce`, however I get a different behaviour when I use it compared to casting to the correct type (using `fromDynamic`). Which is strange, especially because it doesn't crash but just gives a erroneous result ...

Comment: It is not really strange; an incorrect use of `unsafeCoerce` can cause anything to happen, including coincidentally correct behavior, a segfault, or producing a garbage value. In any case, I've included my implementation in the answer.

Comment: Wow !! My mistake was to `unsafeCoerce` the Dynamic itself, instead of it's value. Your code works like a charme. I struggle a bit, because `Delayed` as actuall 2 arguments, so the pattern matching on `[a]` will always fail and the function was compiling but always returning Nothing.

Comment: The pattern match on `[a]` is for the *type* arguments of `Delayed`; it should work regardless of the contents of `Delayed`. If `Delayed` is actually `Delayed a b`, then change that to `[a,b]` and insert an additional `withTypeable b $ ..`.

Comment: I know. I managed to fix it but struggled mainly because just copied paste the code without reading. It compiles, so I assume it worked ;-). But you are right changing to `[a,b`] did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Why not define

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Delayed' = forall a. Delayed' (Delayed a)
```

and then store than in the `Dynamic`?  You can then `cast` it out of the dynamic, `case` on it, and pass the result to `cancel`.  (Depending on what your use case is you may no longer even need the `Dynamic`.)

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way, but I think it may not be the most efficient. Each value is wrapper in a `Delayed'` constructor before being wrapped again in a `Dynamic`.